# Getting Forbidden 403 error with nginx docker container when serving static files

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, angular-cli

I am trying to run my angular-cli project with nginx docker container in development mode. [Here](https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/angular-docker) is the complete boilerplate code.

To avoid every time rebuilding the complete docker image whenever the source code is changed, I am using volumes in my docker compose file and mapping my **dist/{project-name}** path with container's **usr/share/nginx/html** path, and then finally running the Angular project in host machine with **ng build --watch**

But using volumes seems to be causing file read issues to the nginx and it is unable to read index.html

**dev.dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Saurabh Palatkar"
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY /dist/ng-docker /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN ls /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN ps aux | grep nginx
RUN chown -R root:root /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN ls -al /usr
RUN chmod o+x /usr
RUN chmod o+x /usr/share
RUN chmod o+x /usr/share/nginx
RUN chmod o+x /usr/share/nginx/html
# RUN ls /usr/share/nginx/html
# RUN ls /etc/nginx
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml:**

```
version: "2.0"

services:

      angular-nginx-docker:
        image: ng-docker-dev
        build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
        environment:
          NODE_ENV: development
        volumes: 
          - "/dist/ng-docker:/usr/share/nginx/html"
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
```

However, I am able to serve my Angular static files through nginx docker container in prod mode (The only difference I see is, I am not using volumes)
**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "2.0"

services:
  angular-nginx-docker:
    image: ng-docker-prod
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/prod.dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 9229:9229
    command: [nginx, '-g', 'daemon off;']
```

**prod.dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:latest as angular-built
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod --build-optimizer

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Saurabh Palatkar"
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=angular-built /usr/src/app/dist/ng-docker /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

When using volumes, docker will use the host system file permission mode.
I suspect, that your static files on your host, (which you map) does not have permissions to be read by root.

Executing `chmod` in the dockerfile will do nothing, since the files are not in there during build (volumes are mapped on the container run).

I would suggest running `chmod -R o+rx /dist/ng-docker` on the host so every user 
 - including root - on the could read them. If you do not want this, try setting up ACLs specially for root (uid: 0) or modify the container to have a user, which will run nginx, with this same `uid` and `guid` as you have.